# What data can I obtain from this H5 file?

Tags: keras, tensorflow, cnn

I created a CNN model and it is saved in h5 format.
I used the Netron app, where I obtained the model architecture, however `batchnormalization` was not present.
Is there a method to determine whether this h5 model has a `batchnormalization` layer or not. Again, is it possible to know the learning rate?